# Dynamically find array length in C program without using sizeof

Tags: c

I am trying to read a file and store only the digits in the array.

My Example is file.csv

`"1","2","3"
"1","4","6","7"
"12","15"`

Please do not suggest these solutions

`sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` or `*(&arr + 1) - arr`

because both of these don't give the length of array containing actual values. It just gives the length of array when array was declared. I want to know the length of array during run-time when actual values are present.

> The Problem Statement: Find the numOfwords in each line (present in
>   code comments).

My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    char literal, string[4][10][4];
    char *filename = "file.csv";
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen(filename, "r");
    while ((literal = getc(f)) != EOF) {
      if (isdigit(literal)) {
        string[i][j][k] = literal;
        k++;
      } else {
        if (k > 0) {
          string[i][j][k] = '\0';
        }
        k = 0;
      }
      if (literal == ',') j++;
      if (literal == '\n') i++, j = 0;
    }

  int numOfLines = i;
  int total = 0;
  for (int p = 0; p < numOfLines; p++) {
    // int numOfWords = *(&string[p] + 1) - string[p]; // Returns 10
    // int numOfWords = sizeof(string[p]) / sizeof(string[p][0]);  // Returns 10
    // 
    // The Problem Statement: Find the numOfwords in each line.
    printf("numOfWords in line %p: %d\n", numOfWords);
    for (long int q = 0; q < numOfWords; q++) {
      /* code */
      total += atoi(string[p][q]);
    }
  }
  printf("Sum = %d", total);
}
```

Any solution better than this code is appreciated.

Output:

`numOfWords in line 1: 3
numOfWords in line 2: 4
numOfWords in line 3: 2
Sum = 51`

Comment: sounds like a job for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't get the problem. You read something, then you store it in the array. So count each time you are doing this...

Comment: I am looking for something like strlen, that gives me value on each line in an array. I am python dev, so in py I can use `len(arr)`. Hoping to find something like that.

Comment: And a potential refactoring using a 2D array of `int` (or `unsigned`) and scanning forward until you find your first `+/-0-9` and then calling `strtol` (or the other variants, as required) and storing the integer value. That just seems like a more straight forward way to parse the characters into actual numbers.

Comment: Both python `len` and `strlen` are using metadata to get the length. In C it is a marker of the end of string (the `\0` terminator) in python, I would guess it's the length itself stored in some location and modified each time the array is updated. There is no magic.

Comment: The size of an array has nothing to do with the presence of "actual values," but only with the size of the declared array. The `sizeof` operator yields this value at compile time unless the operand is a VLA, in which case it is evaluated at runtime. But if you want to know how many "meaningful" values an array contains, maybe you want to include a sentinel value.

Comment: `char literal; ...     while ((literal = getc(f)) != EOF) {` is  an infinite loop when `char` is  _unsigned_ and insufficient when `char` is _signed_ and `(char)EOF` is read.  Use `int literal;`

Comment: An _array_ size is constant in C, once defined.  `char literal, string[4][10][4];` is **always** a 4x10x4 array of `char`.  Content is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep track on the number of elements you have placed in the array yourself. There is no other way.

Comment: Expanding on this, you can either cache those values when you read them in, saving the maximum value of `j` for each `i`, or you can evaluate at runtime by scanning the appropriate array and counting valid elements.

Answer (score -1):

maybe:

```
typedef struct 
{
    size_t size;
    size_t elementsize;
    unsigned char array[];
}myarray;

myarray *MA_Init(void)
{
    myarray *arr = calloc(1, sizeof(*arr));
    return arr;
}

myarray *MA_alloc(myarray *arr, size_t nelem, size_t elemsize)
{
    narr = realloc(arr, nelem * elemsize + sizeof(*narr));
    if(narray)
    {
        narray -> size = nelem;
        narray -> elementsize = elemsize;
    }
    return narr;
}

int MA_Set(myarray *arr, size_t index, void *elem)
{
    int result = !arr;
    result = result && (index < arr -> size);
    if(result)
    {
        memcpy(&arr -> array[index * arr -> elementsize], elem, arr -> elementsize);
    }

    return result;
}

int MA_Get(myarray *arr, size_t index, void *elem)
{
    int result = !arr;
    result = result && (index < arr -> size);
    if(result)
    {
        memcpy(elem, &arr -> array[index * arr -> elementsize], arr -> elementsize);
    }

    return result;
}
```

...
and so on....

Comment: DV and no comment?

Comment: No downvote by me, but I was tempted by your explanation and the assertiveness of your answer.